# Elastic Beanstalk and Dockerfile ARG instruction

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to pass some arguments to my `docker build` command. I understand that this can be done using the `ARG` instruction within the `Dockerfile`. Now assuming I have the following in my `Dockerfile`.

```
ARG myvar
```

and use the command `docker build --build-arg mvar=myOwnVar ...`, this would work.

However, I am using `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` with `Docker` to build an image and deploy it in a container. So the questions are,

1. Is this possible at all?
2. If, yes how can I ensure that AWS EB passes values to these arguments?

Thanks
Sushil

Comment: wow since '16, yet still no answer, I have the same predicament. I've lost the whole day on this

Comment: There seems to be a related thread on AWS Developer Forum - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230165 . As of today, looks like such a feature is not available.

Answer (score 7):

yesterday I start using AWS EB, I was happy, today I need pass some ARG to my build, found this on the docs

[image]

Very sad

source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html

## Workaround

A possible solution is what I'm doing currently, before run the docker build add some files to the EB and the use it from the Dockerfile

example, lets assume I need a var name `TOKEN` on my docker something like

```
RUN curl http://somemething.com?token=$TOKEN
```

So whay I did was

add a new script file

```
ADD ./curl-thing.sh /curl-thing.sh
```

and the content of

```
if [ -f "./.env"]; then
  source ./.env
fi
```

now add a file name `.ebextensions/my-env.config`, the name no matters just important that exists on the forlder .ebextensions and have the extension .config

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/02_mix_environment.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      TOKEN=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k TOKEN)
      echo "export TOKEN=${TOKEN}" >> ${EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR}/.env
```