# What is the supported way to use a Dockerfile with build-arg(s) and Elastic Beanstalk if we cannot customize the build process?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are lots of questions about using `--build-arg`(s) with building a Dockerfile for Elastic Beanstalk. The issue is that build args are not supported.

Example question (of which there are more with other solutions):

[Elastic Beanstalk and Dockerfile ARG instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698061/elastic-beanstalk-and-dockerfile-arg-instruction)

Without doing these interesting workarounds, what is the common way to deploy a customized docker image so that Elastic Beanstalk can use it and we (the users of eb) can benefit from all benefits that Elastic Beanstalk provides.

Thank you

Update:

If I had to guess, I suspect we are expected to build our images (locally, CI, somewhere) and then push those images to ECR (Elastic Container Registry). Then we have to specify this image in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file. I suspect specifying the `Image` key will supersede a local Dockerfile.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#single-container-docker-configuration.dockerrun

> When using a Dockerfile, do not specify the Image key in the
>   Dockerrun.aws.json file. Elastic Beanstalk always builds and uses the
>   image described in the Dockerfile when one is present.

I think Elastic Beanstalk will look at your last commit, if it is new, it will run a deploy. Since you'd have the `Dockerrun.aws.json` it would not build the dockerfile but rather look to ECR and pull the specified image. So I would guess, before doing a deploy with eb, you'd need to build an image and push to ECR. Steps I suspect:

1. Write some world changing code
2. `git commit -am "world changing code"`
3. run docker build
4. tag docker image
5. push docker image to ecr
6. run eb deploy

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with EB but the sequence of steps you wrote out at the end is the typical way to deploy things with Docker (where the last line could also be `docker-compose up`, `kubectl apply`, `helm upgrade`, ... for different environments).  Browsing through the EB docs, its multi-container mode seems to require this path.  You could set up an automated continuous-integration system to do steps 3-5 or 3-6 for you when you commit.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm whether this works or not? I have the same need. Thanks